# How to detect without delay if a button is pressed continuously?

Tags: c, windows, keyboard, keystroke, kbhit

When you hold down a key on Windows, it presses it once, then there is a small delay of about 0.3 seconds, and only after that delay it starts pressing it continuously.
Something like this:
x (0.3 second delay) xxxxxxxx.

If I use kbhit() to detect if a button is pressed, it doesn't detect the button in those 0.3 seconds of delay, and therefore not run the desired code in that time.

How can I fix this? (Setting the delay to the minimum (0.25s) in the windows controls is no option for me.)

I've already tried every possible combination of kbhit() and getch().

```
while(TRUE){
   if (kbhit()) {
     button = getch();
   } else {
     button = 'x';
   }

   switch (button) {
     case 'a':
       ToDo();
       break;
   }
}
```

When I press a in my example, it should continously, without a 0.3 second break after the first time, run  ToDo(). But it doesn't.

Comment: Aside: there are two delay values: a longer one for the first repeat, a shorter one for subsequent repeats. AFAIK the very first keypress detection has no delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kbhit` does not check if the key is pressed. It only checks if there is a keystroke in the buffer which means something completely different.

In Windows you need to use another functions like `GetAsyncKeyState`

Comment: @Firefighter123 there is a reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/keyboard-input).